# Get json object's value in php if its name contains dots in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json like the following

```
{"root":{
                "version":"1",
                "lastAlarmID":"123",
                "proUser":"1",
                "password":"asd123##",
                "syncDate":"22-12-2014",
                "hello.world":"something"
}
}
```

After `json_decode()`, I can get all the values except that of the last one `hello.world`, since it contain a dot.

`$obj->root->hello.world` doesn't work. I got solutions for doing it in Javascript but I want a solution in php.

Comment: `$obj->root->{'hello.world'}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$obj->root->{'hello.world'}` will work.

ps: `$obj->root->{hello.world}` might not work.

b.t.w: Why not use Array? `json_decode($json, true)` will return Array. Then `$a['root']['hello.world']` will always work.

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
echo $test->root->{'hello.world'};
```

**Check example**

```
<?php

$Data='{"root":{
                "version":"1",
                "lastAlarmID":"123",
                "proUser":"1",
                "password":"asd123##",
                "syncDate":"22-12-2014",
                "hello.world":"something"}
}';
$test=json_decode($Data);
print_r($test);
echo $test->root->{'hello.world'};
?>
```

> Output

```
something
```

Comment: That's working. I have problem only with the last one, which contains a dot

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

First option: convert the object to an array, and either access the properties that way, or convert the name to a safe one:

```
<?php
$array = (array) $obj;
// access the value here
$value = $array['hello.world'];

// assign a safe refernce
$array[hello_world] = &$array['hello.world'];
```

Second option: use quotes and brakets:

```
<?php
$value = $obj->root->{'hello.world'};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use variable variables (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$a = 'hello.world';
$obj->root->$a;
```